# How I can get QMetaObject from just class name?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to get QMetaObject for dynamic creation of object instances.
If I khow the object then QObject::metaObject() is what I need. If I know the class then I can use QObject::staticMetaObject variable. But what should I use if I know only class name as a string value?

Comment: Look into the source for QVariant.  I'm pretty sure it has a method that you might be able to twist into what you want.  It will rely on you registering your types with QVariant, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask for a `QMetaObject`, but say it is for creation purposes.  If that's all you have to do, [QMetaType](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetatype.html) may well be what you need.  You have to register your types with it, but I'm pretty sure QT doesn't have a master list of `QMetaObject`s just floating around by default, so such registration will be necessary no matter what you do.

```
QMetaType::Type id = QMetaType::type("ClassName");
if(id == 0)
    throw something_or_whatever;
ClassName* p = (ClassName*)QMetaType::construct(id);
//act on p
QMetaType::destroy(id, p);
```

Cursory glance at the documentation isn't clear on how the memory for `p` is allocated, but I assume `destroy` takes care of that?  Use at your own risk.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  For something to work as a QMetaType, it needs a public copy constructor, and those are explicitly disallowed for QObjects.

Answer (score 2):

As of Qt5 getting the QMetaObject from just the class name became straightforward:

```
int typeId = QMetaType::type("MyClassName");
const QMetaObject *metaObject = QMetaType::metaObjectForType(typeId);
if (metaObject) {
    // ...
}
```

See also these Qt5 API docs:

- [QMetaObject::type(const char*)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#type)
- [QMetaObject::metaObjectForType(int)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#metaObjectForType)